# IOT token no adding to my Helium wallet when I claim rewards

Tags: solana-program, solana-wallet-adapter, solana-cli, solana-pay

I'm trying to claim my IOT rewards from my hotspots and when I click on "Claim Rewards" within the helium wallet the rewards message appears to say "Rewards Claimed!" after about a minute or so...

However when I when I view my IOT tokens amount it hasn't changed and when I click on the Collectibles tab the amount is still there.

this working fine up to about 2 weeks ago is there any issues on the Solana blockchain at the moment or am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be much appreciated

Regards

Comment: I'm having the same issue AND I have Plenty of SOL in order to do the transaction

Comment: same issue as above and even worse , on 1st attempt to claim my IOT tokens a message appeared failed transaction unable to run tsx , read on reddit that you have to swap some hnt to sol to be able to run the transaction , followed the steps globe icon>browser>helium ...doc etc added my wallet agreed to convert 0.2 hnt to 0.2 sol , then claimed the iot ,app said transaction completed successful but they don't appear on my wallet , the swapped hnt to sol do appear but not the iot tokens and they also vanished from the claim rewards page, on the solana browser i can see the entire transaction as